# globalCompositeOperation at jCanvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, jcanvas, globalcompositeoperation

How can I integrate globalCompositeOperation(or any other plugin which will give me '[multiply](http://henrik.nyh.se/2008/09/photoshop-multiply/)' color manipulation) into [jCanvas](http://calebevans.me/projects/jcanvas/index.php) jQuery plugin?

```
// How do I get this working? //
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'darker';

// With this - //
$("canvas").drawArc({
  fillStyle: "#c7302a",
  x: 100, y: 100,
  radius: 50
});

$("canvas").drawArc({
  fillStyle: "#395797",
  x: 170, y: 100,
  radius: 50,
  opacity: 1
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I solved it. After struggling with it for hours, it was too simple:
I used [context blender](https://github.com/Phrogz/context-blender) plugin.

JS code:

```
$("#canvasReal").drawArc({ // Draw on the real canvas
  fillStyle: "#c7302a",
  x: 100, y: 100,
  radius: 50
});

$("#canvasOff").drawArc({ // Draw on the off screen canvas
  fillStyle: "#395797",
  x: 150, y: 100,
  radius: 50
});

// Blend off-screen canvas onto the real canvas
    var over = canvasOff.getContext('2d'); 
    var under = canvasReal.getContext('2d');
    over.blendOnto(under,'multiply');
```

HTML code:

```
<canvas width="500" height="250" id="canvasReal"></canvas>
<canvas width="500" height="250"id="canvasOff" style="display:none;"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

For the record, jCanvas has a `compositing` property, the value for which maps to `ctx.globalCompositeOperation`.

```
$("canvas").drawArc({
  fillStyle: "#c7302a",
  x: 100, y: 100,
  radius: 50,
  compositing: 'darker'
});
```

-Caleb

Comment: Better late than never?